# Microsoft Chart ... Make Transparent

Tags: charts, data-visualization, mschart

I am using Microsoft Charting to display two series.

Is it possible to make one of the series transparent to show the series behind?

Something like the following:

> http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/chart/ChartType/AreaChart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define the Series color with an alpha component

`chart.Series["Default"].Color = Color.FromArgb(120, 0, 155, 155);`